# internal load balancer with static ip and supports HTTPS in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

what is the best way to create an internal load balancer with a static IP address that supports HTTPS termination in the EKS cluster?

Answer (score 0):

AWS NLB can run in private subnets and support both TLS termination and static IP. Checkout the [Features](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/network-load-balancer/) section. You use the [AWS LB Controller](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html) to provision the NLB in your EKS.

Comment: would this be achievable without the use of a controller? so I would like to have an NLB and route traffic to a custom Nginx docker image. And with this setup, I am having handshake issues with the load balancer.

Comment: This is the error I am getting when testing with curl:
`* found 129 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 520 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.`

Comment: You can expose your service via `NodePort`, then add your worker nodes to the NLB target group. The error you shown possibly due to the node security group didn't open the `NodePort`.